# Does the だ get dropped after an い-adjective

Tags: i-adjectives

I was told how an older non-native lady would say "it's okay!" and that it was perceived to be just like that person and cute many because it was grammatically incorrect. She would say, いいだよ

Now I didn't know that rule but I was sure I had heard いいだよ before. It is such a simple statement but even these things trip me up.

So I'm guessing the rule is like

```
だ after な-adjectives, nouns
No だ after い-adjectives
```

Can I get something definitive on this please?
What about adverbs?

Comment: Are you sure it's wasn't いいんだよ and you just couldn't hear the ん clearly?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. いい is an い-adjective, so you expect  no だ according to your rule, but you are citing an example that has だ.

Comment: @istrasci That might be one possibility, but the OP might be referring to the kind of speech used by a fictional old lady character acted by 志村けん。

Comment: The old lady is a lady I know. 
The example I cited was from what I thought I heard, and as istrasci asked, I might not have heard it correctly and just stored that in my brain rule book incorrectly. 
As for the cultural reference, I don't know about 志村けん. 
The point of the question was to nail down the rule.

Comment: @istrasci please add your suggestion as an answer so i can mark it.

Comment: You're the boss...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it's wasn't いいんだよ and you just couldn't hear the ん clearly?

Comment: ... Haha, OK.  I appreciate receiving the answer, but feel like this simple response doesn't warrant it.

Answer (score 7):

There are regions where "いいだよ" gets said (http://www.geocities.co.jp/Technopolis/1775/mikawa.html), but it's not standard 標準語　Japanese. With adverbs, it probably depends. I don't think you could say "すぐにだ”, but "ときどきだ" sounds OK.

Comment: "standard 標準語 Japanese" = redundant.  Just sayin'.

Comment: そうだ。だって、いいだよ。(笑)

Comment: I heard "いいだ" a lot in Akita prefecture.